# Screenshot via Java applet

Tags: c#, java, applet

I'm very interested in 1 question - HOW to make a screennshot of a client desktop for futher sending to web service or to my Silverlight application.
I'm going to write an applicaton for screencasting.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Remember that the applet must be signed. I also remember reading somewhere on here that it's a difficult to get above 1fps (but that may be sufficient).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but I think there's something in the Robot class that will help you.

EDIT:

From the Robot API:

```
public BufferedImage createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)

    Creates an image containing pixels read from the screen. This image does not include the mouse cursor.

    Parameters:
        screenRect - Rect to capture in screen coordinates 
    Returns:
        The captured image
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well!

And other side of my question is  - how to organize interaction between SL application and this java applet without installing anything in a client machine?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the Robot class.